# python pickle: dump only unique list to pickled file

Tags: python, list, unique, pickle, dump

I have a function that generates a list of gene names for each sample.  I want to save this list and reuse it some other time.  However, when dumping into the pickled file, I like to read the pickle file first, and only select to dump only the genes that are not in the pickle files.  I dont want my pickle file to contain repetitive gene list as throughout time, it will create a huge pickle file.

e.g.

If my pickled file already contains the following genes: 'a', 'ab', 'ac' and the list I have newly created is:

```
unique_genes_list = ["a", "ab", "ac", "ad"]
```

Then I only want to dump the 'ad' to pickle.  Any nice way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you only want to dump a single object? Or a new one for each run? In other words, would `["a", "ab", "ac"]` be stored in one object and `['ad']` in another?

Comment: ["a", "ab", "ac", "ad"] would be generated again from another run but I dont want to dump "a", "ab", "ac in there as they are already present in the pickle file.  I just want the 'ad' to be dumped.

Comment: My answer will overwrite the comprehensive list of unique genes into the file. If you'd rather just store `['ad']`, I'll add an edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to add the new gene, `'ad'`, to the existing list of genes, here is how you can read in your old data from pickle, add the new gene and re-pickle:

```
import pickle

unique_genes_list = ["a", "ab", "ac", "ad"]
with open('some/path', 'rb') as in_pickle:
    old_data = pickle.load(in_pickle) ## ["a", "ab", "ac"]

## Adds 'ad' and any other new data
old_data.extend([x for x in unique_genes_list if not x in old_data]) 

## Save the new combined data
with open('some/path', 'wb') as out_pickle: 
    pickle.dump(old_data, out_pickle) ## dumps ["a", "ab", "ac", "ad"] overwriting old pickle
```

#### Edit:

If you're hoping to only retrieve the uniques and just pickle `['ad']`, then here's how you would do that

```
import pickle

unique_genes_list = ["a", "ab", "ac", "ad"]
with open('some/path', 'rb') as in_pickle:
    old_data = pickle.load(in_pickle) ## ["a", "ab", "ac"]

## Gets just 'ad' or any other unique in a new list
new_genes = [x for x in unique_genes_list if not x in old_data] ##['ad']

## Save the new unique data
with open('some/new/path', 'wb') as out_pickle: 
    pickle.dump(new_genes, out_pickle) ## dumps ["ad"]
```